# Computers used in Computer-Based Examinations?

Tags: linux, windows

So I just gave a computer-based examination. I don't know how it is in other countries but I have given 2-3 computer-based online exams here in India, and I have noticed that in these computers, the browser window(I can only assume it is a browser, it may be some other program) is like fixed on the screen in fullscreen, I can't see any close/minimize buttons or anything, the entire screen is covered by this program and the window can't be closed or minimized. I am just curious how this is possible. Do these computers have some special Operating System installed or is there a way to do this in Windows(or linux)? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

[Kiosk mode](https://superuser.com/tags/kiosk/info) can limit a user's interaction within an application or OS. Kiosk mode or kiosk software is used to lock down the GUI for security and to prevent unauthorized functions. Kiosk mode can also be used to limit the user's interaction to being able to run only one application as a guest user on a computer.

Ubuntu is often used as the operating system for kiosks because it is a popular, free OS that is easy to install. For more information about how an Ubuntu kiosk works see [How to make Ubuntu 14.04 a kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490820/how-to-make-ubuntu-14-04-a-kiosk). The accepted answer to this question was written by the blogger who also wrote [Building a kiosk computer with Ubuntu 14.04 and Chrome](https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/) and [Converting an existing Ubuntu Desktop into a Chrome kiosk](https://thepcspy.com/read/converting-ubuntu-desktop-to-kiosk/).